# philosophy-modern as bib-style and philosophy-verbose as cite-style

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-philosophy

I'm writing my second thesis in LaTeX, but this time my professor is more 'aggressive' for the bibliography. Each time I use a `\footfullcite`, the citation in footnote must use the complete schema (like in the `philosophy-verbose` style) but the bibliography at the end of the document must be done like the `philosophy-modern` style. I have tried different combinations of these two styles, I've read the documentation of the 'biblatex-philosophy bundle' but nothing.

My code that is right for the bibliography is:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
    title = {Synthesis of Enantiopure Alcohols},
    volume = {71},
    number = {17},
    journal = {J. Org. Chem.},
    author = {Test T.},
    month = aug,
    year = {2006}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[
    bibstyle=philosophy-modern,
    citestyle=philosophy-verbose,
    backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\printbibliography

First\footfullcite[9]{test}, second\footfullcite[18]{test} and third time.\footfullcite{test}

\end{document}
```

and my code that is almost right (because the Id and Ibidem are not shown) for the `\footfullcite` is:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
    title = {Synthesis of Enantiopure Alcohols},
    volume = {71},
    number = {17},
    journal = {J. Org. Chem.},
    author = {Test T.},
    month = aug,
    year = {2006}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[
    style=philosophy-verbose,
    backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

\printbibliography

First\footfullcite[9]{test}, second\footfullcite[18]{test} and third time.\footfullcite{test}

\end{document}
```

Please, anyone has my problem?

Comment: Why do you use `\footfullcite` all the time, can't you use `\footcite`? In that case you get ibid and all, but then that doesn't seem to be the main issue, so why do you mention it in your second MWE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `\footcite`s and `\footfullcite` use `\usedriver` to call the bibdriver for the cited items. The bibdriver, however, comes from the `.bbx` styl, while the rest of the citations is controlled by the `.cbx` file. The two styles in a way collide over `\usedriver`.

It seems as though `biblatex-philsophy` already has the code in place to make sure that you can properly use the bib drivers outside the bibliography.

It is not that easy to call the reset macro though. Since the code was written as an option for `\printbibliography`, we can get it back as `\csuse{KV@blx@bib2@restoreclassic@default}`.

So you could try

```
\AtEveryCite{\csuse{KV@blx@bib2@restoreclassic@default}}
```

which gets you a "classic" layout for the bib drivers in citations.

Alternatively, you could insert the call to the macro only into `cite:full`, where it is needed.

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%OK
  \iftoggle{cbx:shorthandintro}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
     \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}%
     \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
       \usedriver
         {\csuse{KV@blx@bib2@restoreclassic@default}%
          \iftoggle{cbx:scauthorscite}
            {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{scdefault}}%
            {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}}%
         {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
     \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    bibstyle=philosophy-modern,
    citestyle=philosophy-verbose,
    backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%OK
  \iftoggle{cbx:shorthandintro}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
     \global\toggletrue{cbx:fullcite}%
     \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
       \usedriver
         {\csuse{KV@blx@bib2@restoreclassic@default}%
          \iftoggle{cbx:scauthorscite}
            {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{scdefault}}%
            {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}}%
         {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
     \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography

First\footcite[9]{sigfridsson}, second\footcite[18]{sigfridsson} and third time.\footcite{sigfridsson} and\footcite{cicero} lorem\footcite{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Note that I used `\footcite` instead of `\footfullcite` to get proper handling of "ibid" and subsequent short citations.

Comment: Thanks, the solution is working, I'm now using the\footcite instead of \footfullcite, although when I put the \footcite in a \caption the "ibid" is not handled, do you no why? Thanks again @moewe

Comment: I resolved putting \footnotemark in the caption and \footcite after the figure. It works!!